# $_SESSION not saving

Tags: php, session, session-variables, session-cookies

$_SESSION is not saving, it seems that the path is not writtable. Permissions are: 755, and in **phpinfo();** says sessions are **enabled**.

```
<?php

    session_start();
    ob_start();

    if(isset($_GET["logout"])){
        unset($_SESSION["userid"]);
        header("Location: index.php");
        die();
    }

    if(isset($_POST["username"]) && isset($_POST["password"])){
        $_SESSION["userid"] = 1;
        header("Location: index.php");
        die();
    }

    $uid = 0;
    if($_SESSION["userid"] && $_SESSION["userid"]>0){
        $uid = $_SESSION["userid"];
    }

    if (!is_writable(session_save_path())) {
        echo 'Session path "'.session_save_path().'" is not writable for PHP!'; 
    }

    echo $uid;

?>
```

$uid is always 0.

I'm getting `Session path "" is not writable for PHP!`

Comment: Check your PHP error log -- are there any warnings about `headers already sent`?

Comment: @Barmar No, there aren't :(

Comment: could be possibly your php.ini has an incorrect setting for sessions, is it shared server? anyway check session.save_path in php.ini also check the session dir is writeable

Comment: What path isn't writable? `755` means it's writable only to the owner, what is the ownership of the path?

Comment: Have you tried to explicitly set the value of save_path to a directory that you know is writable by the user executing the script rather than just using the default value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, the thing is it's a domain inside a domain inside a shared server, maybe that's why it had problems with $_SESSIONS, what I just did what host it in the root domain of that shared server. Now it does work.